# Select sound files + iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, audio

Can we select sound files from iPhone with a particular length?

Comment: Sound files that are stored on the iPhone device. Length is to be in seconds. I want the user to select the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone apps only have access to files that are stored within the application's own storage area. So, you cannot access the files that the user has loaded into iTunes. You can only view their metadata and cause them to be played.

However, the meta-data of the iTunes library does include length, so you could examine that metadata instead of examining the files, and select ones with a length that you want.